# Xcode - Set week of month, then get the week of year

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdateformatter

Currently trying to use NSDateFormatter and NSDateComponents to set the week number for a month, then find the week of year that would be.

Let’s say we have a date: 20/05/2020, then set the week number to 0, or 1, or 2, etc.. then find out the week of year from that.

So far with NSDateComponents I’ve tried doing:

```c
NSDate *date = self.date; // 20/05/2020
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:date];

[components setWeekOfMonth:1];
NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

NSInteger weekOfYear = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear fromDate:newDate].weekOfYear;
```

I'm always getting the output `18`.

Expected output:

```
Change week of month to: 1 | output: 19 (4th)
Change week of month to: 2 | output: 20 (11th)
Change week of month to: 3 | output: 21 (18th)
Change week of month to: 4 | output: 22 (25th)
```

Comment: The first week of month is one, not zero.

Comment: Even when changing it to 1, 2, 3, etc.. same result

Comment: I quickly run your code (setting week of month to 1 and adding the missing trailing semicolons) and it worked.

Comment: The week of year is still 18 for me when I change the week of day to 1, 2, or 3. What output are you getting?

Comment: Yes, I get 18, too, but this is actually the proper number. To change the week of month is not needed because with the given components (month, year) you get the 1. of the current month anyway.

Comment: Do you know a way of me getting the output i'm looking for then?

Comment: What output are you looking for?

Comment: updated question - added expected output

Comment: May 4th in 2020 is week 19

Comment: that's not the point really, you can see what i'm trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is setting `setWeekOfMonth` in the date components has no effect.

Instead set the `weekday` and `weekdayOrdinal`

```
NSDate *date = self.date; // 20/05/2020
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:date];
components.weekday = 2;
components.weekdayOrdinal = 3;
NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

NSInteger weekOfYear = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear fromDate:newDate].weekOfYear;
```

---

This is a different approach:

It calculates the first monday in the current month, then it enumerates the next mondays until the end of the month.

```
- (NSArray *)yearOfWeeksInCurrentMonth
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components: NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    components.weekday = 2;
    components.weekdayOrdinal = 1;

    NSDate *firstMonday = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    NSInteger weekOfYear = [calendar component:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear fromDate:firstMonday];

    __block NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    [result addObject:@[firstMonday, @(weekOfYear)]];
    NSDateComponents *weekComponents = [calendar components: NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:firstMonday];
    [calendar enumerateDatesStartingAfterDate:firstMonday matchingComponents:weekComponents options:NSCalendarMatchNextTime usingBlock:^(NSDate * _Nullable date, BOOL exactMatch, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        if (date != nil) {
            if ( [calendar component:NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:date] > components.month ) {
                *stop = YES;
            } else {
                NSInteger weekOfYear = [calendar component:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear fromDate:date];
                [result addObject:@[date, @(weekOfYear)]];
            }
        }
    }];
    return [result copy];
}
```

The return value is an array containing the date (NSDate) and the corresponding weekOfYear (NSNumber)

```
(
        (
        "2020-05-03 22:00:00 +0000",
        19
    ),
        (
        "2020-05-10 22:00:00 +0000",
        20
    ),
        (
        "2020-05-17 22:00:00 +0000",
        21
    ),
        (
        "2020-05-24 22:00:00 +0000",
        22
    )
)
```